# Command line console app: security aspects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, console-application

I have a console application with allow some parameters to be passed. Two of them are user and password for database connection what worries me. So another not authorized user can see them by scrolling down/up keys.

So what are the best approaches to solve this?

I have thought to implement one of the following solutions:

1. Once application starts, delete command line history.
2. Pass them encrypted through a xml file and then from code read the xml and decrypt them.

In case 1, I do not know if it is possible to do from c# and using .net framework 3.5.

In case 2, user must encrypt them using another app and put them encrypted in the xml so it is a bit cumbersome.

Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What about using [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) to obtain the parameters?

Comment: Get the console app to ask for username and password.

Comment: @Phylogenesis in my case this is not a valid solution as this console application will be automatically executed once a day through windows scheduler task.

Comment: @DaveBecker the same I told Phylogenesis.

Comment: You never mentioned that at all in your question. If the console app is executed by the scheduler then how can an unauthorised user use the cursor keys to see the command history? I would suggest that you do both, in the absence of, say, `-p:password` have the console app ask for the password otherwise use the parameter. Fits both scenarios.